# How to remove blogger widget white margins?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml, blogger

**Screenshot:**

[image: white spaces]

I wanted to use a blogger contact form widget on my page with bootstrap.
How can I make that part full width and responsive without these white margins at the bottom and sides of the widget?

widget html:
    
            
              
        
             Fale
                
                  Conosco

css:

```
.widget{ 
text-align:center;
background-color:#222222;}
.body { 
display:inline;
background-color:#222222;}
.navbar { 
font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif; }
.content-header{ 
font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive; 
color:#fcc500; 
font-size: 45px; } 
#reel { 
padding-top:50px; 
height:100%; 
color:#fff; 
background-color:black; } 
#about { 
font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif; 
padding-top: 50px; 
text-align: center; 
width: 100%; 
height: 400px; 
background: #222222; 
color : #fff; } 
#services { 
font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif; 
padding-top: 50px; 
text-align: center; 
width: 100%;  
height: 400px; 
background: #222222; 
color : #fff; } 
div#contact { 
font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif; 
padding-top: 50px; 
text-align: center; 
background: #222222; 
color : #fff; } 
#footer { 
font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif; 
text-align: center; 
background: #222222; 
color : #fff; }
.main-inner {
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Sorry but your statements don't make any sense. Please rephrase your problem, and if possible post a jsfiddle of the code.

Comment: sorry...neither (code or english) are my first language...and I didn't knew what I need to ask for to fix the page...Maybe it's better now? the site is https://playtey.com thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following style may work:

```
body,html,section{

  margin:0 !important;
  padding:0 important;
  width:100% !important;

}
```

But this is not a permanent way of solving your problem. You must find out exactly where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect your page. Focus that element and observe, you can see the surplus.

Or use reset.css